# Is it possible to test SQL queries on local tables?

Tags: python, sql, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I would like to write and test my SQL queries without connecting to an SQL database. Is that possible? Most examples connect to a mysql database, but the one I have to test against is a mssql.

As one can create these tables in sqlalchemy, can one not add data to them locally (before committing) and execute queries on them, such that one can assert that the queries work as expected?

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

metadata_obj = MetaData()

from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String

user = Table(
    "user",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("user_id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("user_name", String(16), nullable=False),
    Column("email_address", String(60)),
    Column("nickname", String(50), nullable=False),
)
```

Comment: To test SQL you need some kind of database access. (At least if you want to verify more than syntax.)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/-SXv3GHO can perhaps be useful?

Comment: You could install SQL server (developer edition). It is free to use for developer purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it turns out that the standard way to do these tests are to place ones data in sqlite "in memory", and then make queries. It works pretty well, but it is not all functionality from MSSQL that is available in sqlite.